# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I made an analysis of a legacy code (it's Spring application) and found both `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` initialized in Spring context. I know that only one instance of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` should exist in Spring context. My question is if this rule is the same applying to `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Is it a mistake to have both of them into context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple property configures can be registered. But if both PlaceholderConfigurer refer to same set of properties, then its a mis-configuration and should be avoided.

Otherwise, when registering multiple PlaceholderConfigurer, it is important that the order of bean is correctly specified. So spring can resolve the right values for the placeholders.

You can find a good read here.

[Spring Properties](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually my problem with autowiring(@Value)in spring web application(spring-mvc). I have property file and two PPC's(mentioned in the question) in parent context. However in my child context I can't autowire property using(@Value) and I was thinking the problem is in this. I defined another PPC in child context, but I wanted to reuse PPC defined in parent context. In your reference(point 8) is described dependency between child-parent context. However I found a defect which describes why does this happen https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8994

Answer (score 5):

**PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** is more flexible through taking advantage of the Environment and PropertySource mechanisms also made available in Spring 3.1.

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is still appropriate for use when:

1. the spring-context module is not available (i.e., one is using Spring's BeanFactory API as opposed to ApplicationContext).
2. existing configuration makes use of the "systemPropertiesMode" and/or "systemPropertiesModeName" properties. Users are encouraged to move away from using these settings, and rather configure property source search order through the container's Environment; however, exact preservation of functionality may be maintained by continuing to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

**PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** This class is designed as a general replacement for PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring 3.1 applications. It is used by default to support the property-placeholder element in working against the spring-context-3.1 XSD, whereas spring-context versions <= 3.0 default to PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to ensure backward compatibility.